# in a tree nodes I want to calculate shortest path with route

Tags: path, tree, shortest

In a tree of nodes I want to calculate shortest path with route as given in images by excel formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put values connecting the points!

For example:

From A -->B distance is 2

Then its just the matter of using a A* search Traversal, add up all of the routes that leads to it then compare them.

To be honest, you would be better off using a IDE to do this kind of thing.

(Also make sure your paths are joined, just a hint :) )

Comment: thanks for the reply But It is very important to find out the points with in start and end points, which may from any direction. if my starting point is "A" and end is "I", then I want (1) A-B-C-I (2) A-G-E-C-I. By this with using vlookup I can Add distance between A-B, B-C, C-I and also of A-G, G-E, E-C, C-I from both Find the minimum distance with points name, when ever I want to add more name I have no need to do more.   I am trying to do the same but fail to do it. Please me if any answer you have.

Comment: still waiting for the update , now i also needed in above "all possible paths'', in vba excel

Comment: can it possible in vba program with detail of all other optional path

Comment: No one has any answare. I thing it is not possible in vba

Comment: Update: Wow this was a long time ago i answered this but i just re-read what you needed. If i'm assuming that you want to loop thought the list until you find the next letter (node) then i'm afraid, there isn't really a way to loop thought a list. Even if there was a way you would need to remove that letter (node) from the list which as far as i know is impossible.

Comment: Excel is for more statistical analysis and financial number crunching than a line by line. There MIGHT be a way to do this but as far as i am concerned this would be inefficient or requiring many checking cells to see if the path as been completed. Vb (Visual BAsic) wold really be more suitable as with the basic GUI i assume you want is easier to code and to work out solutions. Here is the link to a site that might help you grasp the basics of VB. its free as well. https://www.codecademy.com/ . Well hopefully i have answered your question as close as you wanted it to be answered.